# Why VS Code's "remote tunnel" needs to sign into Github account?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, github-codespaces, remote-tunnel

Just wondering what is the link between VS Code's remote tunnel feature and GitHub account? When we try to activate remote tunnel, it asks to sign in to GitHub and then apparently link to that account. I am wondering why? If my machine is a server then why do I need Github in between this setup?

Comment: Different from what you imagined, the tunnel created goes through Microsoft servers, so you need to present a valid GitHub or Microsoft account to pass authentication. That's what the link in the answer below revealed.

Answer (score 2):

> How are tunnels secured?

> Both **hosting and connecting to a tunnel requires authentication with the same Github or Microsoft account on each end**. In both cases, VS Code will make outbound connections to a service hosted in Azure; no firewall changes are generally necessary, and VS Code doesn't set up any network listeners.

Cited from: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels#_how-are-tunnels-secured